# ARM9 Kernel 2.6.10 GPIO pin interrupts return IRQ_HANDLED

Tags: linux, arm, masking, gpio

I'm trying to better understand the interaction between the "return IRQ_HANDLED" statement used in a GPIO pin-based interrupt handler (top-half) and the GPIO pin hardware. In particular, consider the hypothetical situation wherein a device has pulled a GPIO pin low to indicate that it needs attention.  This causes the associated (top half) interrupt handler to be invoked. Now assume that the top-half handler queues up some work and then returns with "return IRQ_HANDLED" but that for whatever reason the interrupt has not been cleared on the device that generated it (i.e. the device is holding the GPIO pin in the low state).  Does invocation of "return IRQ_HANDLED" cause the interrupt to be regenerated? I ask this in the context of the following article:

http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch06lev1sec4

"Reentrancy and Interrupt Handlers
Interrupt handlers in Linux need not be reentrant. When a given interrupt handler is executing, the corresponding interrupt line is masked out on all processors, preventing another interrupt on the same line from being received. Normally all other interrupts are enabled, so other interrupts are serviced, but the current line is always disabled. Consequently, the same interrupt handler is never invoked concurrently to service a nested interrupt. This greatly simplifies writing your interrupt handler."

The above comment indicates that upon invocation of an interrupt handler, the interrupt line for that interrupt is masked. I'm trying to figure out if the invocation of "return IRQ_HANDLED" is what unmasks the interrupt line. And, with respect to the hypothetical case described above, what would happen if I "return IRQ_HANDLED" yet the device has not really had its interrupt cleared and hence is still holding the GPIO pin in a low (triggered) state.  More specifically, will this cause the interrupt to be generated again such that the processor never has a chance to do the work queued when the interrupt first occurred. I.e., would this lead to an interrupt storm wherein the processor could be interrupted endlessly thus not allowing any useful processing to occur. I should add that I ask this question in the context of a single CPU linux ARM9 system (Phytec LPC3180) running kernel 2.6.10.

Thanks in advance,

Jim

PS: I'm not clear as to the difference between enabling/disabling an interrupt (in particular, an interrupt associated with a particular GPIO pin) and masking/unmasking the same GPIO interrupt.

Comment: Google 'level triggered interrupts' and 'edge triggered interrupts' for some background here.

Comment: Hi Pete - Thanks for the suggestion. I understand the differences between edge- and level-triggered interrupts from a hardware perspective. It's the linux handling side of things where I'm struggling. I'm coming up the learning curve, but I have a ways to go. We have four uarts whose int. lines are connect to a GPIO line. If one or more chips pull this line low, thus generating an interrupt, what happens if the interrupt is never acknowledge and the line goes high again. Does the interrupt "go away" from the kernel's perspective? And so on... - Thanks! - Jim

Comment: So is your GPIO interrupt edge or level triggered?

Comment: Pete - We have the GPIO pin configured for level interrupts.  In case it's useful, the devices are MAX3107 uarts and we have four sharing this line. - Thanks - Jim